# Drive filled up after connection to NAS was broken

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

This has probably been covered before but I'm not sure what do call it to find it.

I use NFS in my fstab to connect my Synology to /media. My Synology went offline for a bit but some file transfers continued and filled up my root drive, apparantly in /media on the root drive. My Ubuntu server would not come up so I did a Live USB and was able to get in and remove enough files for it to come up. When it finally rebooted, fstab reconnected the Synology but I don't seem to be able to get access to the files that were incorrectly stored at /media as that now shows the Synology share. (Hopefully that makes sense.)

How can I get access to the /media on the drive AND the Synology at the same time so I can move the files to the Synology and free up the precariously full root drive?

Comment: Please include the output of `findmnt --fstab` in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you've just hidden the files under the mountpoint - see for example [Mounting Flashdrive - mounted to home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865574/mounting-flashdrive-mounted-to-home-directory) (although unless you're using the NAS as something critical like your home dir it should be straightforward to unmount it and mount it somewhere else, like `/mnt`)

Comment: You can either mount the NAS somewhere else or unmount it and use removeable media. Whichever is easier for you.

Comment: Doh! That was too simple. I was making it way too difficult. Changed the fstab to mount them at /mnt and I was able to see the files and move them correctly. Thank you so much!